# SSRS - hh:mm:ss tt showing as "hh:mm:ss tt" and not an actual time

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008

still very new to reports and all, currently trying to modify the time format for a report and I'd like it to appear as (ex.) **02:30:05 PM** rather than the current/default 14:30:05.

Here's what I have so far:

```
="between the hours of " & Format(Parameters!StartTime.Value, "hh:mm:ss tt") & " and " & Format(Parameters!EndTime.Value, "hh:mm:ss tt") & " (" & Parameters!TimeZone.Label & ")"
```

The problem is that running the report it comes up as "between the hours of hh:mm:ss tt and hh:mm:ss tt" instead of "between the hours of 02:30:05 PM and 03:30:05 PM".

Any ideas as to why that might be? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the data type for your parameter is causing this. You most likely currently have it set to `Text`. In the Parameter Properties, change it to `Date/Time`. This will allow the `Format` function to interpret it as a date and time instead of a string.

Alternatively, you can cast the parameter value as a date in the expression like this:

```
Format(CDate(Parameters!StartTime.Value), "hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Comment: Used the second method and it works great - thank you!